# What's the creature whose meat Obi-Wan is cutting while working in Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

What's the creature whose meat Obi-Wan is cutting while working in Tatooine?

It seems to be a [manta-ray-like creature](https://www.thewrap.com/obi-wan-kenobi-episode-1-episode-2-recap-review/).

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to put that link? It seems to lead to a page of many articles, none of which have a picture. If there's a description in the text, could you quote it in the body of your question?

Comment: looks like salmon ;)

Comment: I thought that it was a krayt dragon, but a google of those comse up with a different skeleton.  Interesting.

Comment: In The Book Of Bobba Fett, it was mentioned that Tatooine used to have large oceans, it might be a remnant (or a species that adapted itself).

Comment: Obviously, this is the original "[Land Shark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_NS2H55dxI)".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This specimen is known as ***Tibidon** sand whale*

[image: Tibidon carving station][1]

> **Tibidon Carving Station**

> Ben Kenobi toils at a station where massive **flying tibidon sand whales** are carved up for their meat. After a long day of such grueling labor, Kenobi makes enough money to survive on Tatooine. The carcass of a massive **tibidon sand whale** has become a carving station operated by desperate but dedicated workers, who chop up the creature’s meat for sale in the city of Anchorhead.

Refs:

- https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tibidon_sand_whale
- [1] https://www.starwars.com/databank/tibidon-carving-station

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have a solid (non-fandom) source for this?

Comment: Thanks @DavidW Yes: www.starwars.com/databank/tibidon-carving-station

Comment: Yes, evidence lifted directly from the source material is much preferred to evidence from fan-written and edited websites. You should also try to include relevant evidence (such as quotes or images) within your answer, rather than just linking to a page with such evidence, because doing so ensures that said evidence will be preserved within your answer, rather than being dependent on another website.

Comment: Thanks @LogicDictates image, citation and link added

Answer (score 15):

The audio description track (second audio program) describes it as a

> "Sand whale".

Then states that they are processing

> "whale meat".

It then calls the place where they process the whale meat the

> "Sand Whale Station".

Comment: thank you, i watched again to verify.

Comment: Do the transport it and weigh it at the WhaleWeigh Station?

Comment: could be a live action purgil that died and crashed on the planet

Comment: @Valorum Almost; before they get there they have to go through the WhaleWeigh Way Station.

Comment: _I've been working on the WhaleRoad all the live long day. I've been working on WhaleRoad just to pass the time away._